# How do I put a hyperlink as the text-overflow?

Tags: html, css

With `text-overflow: ellipsis`, is it possible to make *only* the ellipsis

1. clickable
2. styled like a hyperlink

If so, how?

The goal is that when text overflows, the ellipsis can be used to show the overflown text, and it is clear to the user that the ellipsis is clickable.

Comment: Considering that `text-overflow` is a CSS property, I'm pretty sure it's not the appropriate tool for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

```
.truncate {
    width: 22px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

and use this class in a div for anchor tag :

```
<div class="truncate"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></div>
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/WaAL5/

***Updated solution*** : http://jsfiddle.net/WaAL5/1/

Comment: it does make the ellipsis clickable, but it has the side effect of making the whole anchor text clickable.  also, it is not styled like a hyperlink on firefox 30.

Comment: the problem is that reducing the width has nothing to do with the question.  the question is about `text-overflow` not about complicated anchors.

Comment: your updated fiddle doesn't show the ellipsis in firefox 30 and doesn't show the text in chrome 34.  almost no one is using firefox 7.  1. *only* ellipsis part clickable.  No.  2. Styled like anchor.  No.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using JQuery you could do something like this -

```
<div class="truncate"><a href="Javascipt:">Some Link</a></div>

$(".truncate a").each( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var linkWidth = $this.width();
    var contWidth = $this.parent().width();

    if (linkWidth >= contWidth) {
        var linkDesc = $this.text();
        $this.text('\u2026').addClass('ellipsis');
        $this.parent().prepend(linkDesc);    
    }    
});

.truncate {
    width: 70px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.truncate a.ellipsis {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/5zEzX/9/)

This has the benefit of being cross-platform compatible which the CSS ellipsis property does not.

#### Edit

I still don't think that what you want to accomplish can be done with pure CSS, but this might be a better solution for you JQuery-wise.

Comment: i don't see what this has to do with overflow?

Comment: It's a more reliable way of doing what you want to accomplish. You can't do what you're looking for with pure HTML/CSS, that CSS property isn't meant for that. When an ellipsis is added by the overflow property it's added by the browser and the browser determines how it works and what it looks like.

Comment: I think your comment answers the question more than your answer.

Comment: I think this new modification will possibly better server your needs.

Comment: that looks pretty close.  i just need to rearrange things so there is only an anchor when there is an ellipsis.

Comment: There you go, I've updated the demo to reflect what you were looking for.

Comment: i think you forgot to save your fiddle but i saved it as http://jsfiddle.net/5zEzX/11/ .  I think you overcomplicated it, so I've made http://jsfiddle.net/5zEzX/12/

Comment: Cool trick, I've never used scrollWidth/clientWidth. I like it!

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `text-overflow`.

http://jsfiddle.net/WaAL5/2/

```
<div class="truncate">Facebook</div><a href="http://www.facebook.com">...</a>
```

css:

```
.truncate {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That's an idea, but how do you know when the text will overflow and when it won't?